# Teamcity 9 and 10 issue

Tags: teamcity

We are using Teamcity 9 and 10 both have the same VCS Configuration(SVN), 
unfortunately teamcity 10 gives various types of errors:

```
1. "%Directory%" has been locked 
2. Failed to update "%Directory%"
```

However teamcity 9 is working fine with the same configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be an issue caused by an agent-side checkout, which is default option since TeamCity 10. Did you use server-side checkout in 9? If yes, why not to try server-side checkout in 10?

Comment: Yes you r right

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I have found this issue.
Issue is that Teamcity 10 by default use **Prefer to checkout files on agent (recommended)** on **VCS checkout mode**
Please refer below URL

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Mode

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/792611?flash_digest=05576792fda1848ea2c47df25432939322e6038c